# Youtube API video-only search returning a channel object

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When I try to receive video-only results using the following URL:
"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=10&order=relevance&q=" + search + "&type=video&key=" + apiKey;

and I attempt to search for '21 savage' or 21%20savage (this is used in my private discord music bot, and a friend had searched for this), I receive 9 video results and 1 channel result. Isn't the 'type=video' supposed to specify to return videos only?

In three weeks of moderate use of this method to search for videos, this is the first incident I have come across obtaining a channel in my video results.

Thanks,

Uebios

Comment: I can confirm this issue, I get the same results with almost the same query, but with no `order` param and a query of 'madeon' (getting the Madeon channel as the last result of 10): https://gist.github.com/jrajav/496858e65bd153dab24a937e98a7875a

Comment: `type=video` supposed to only retrieve a particular type of resource which is in your case, `video`. You may file a [report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803) regarding this issue.

Comment: @abielita May we? http://i.imgur.com/6RjzOev.png

Comment: as a get round, I would search for more than 10. then in the snippet data, filter the channels out. I then will have only videos and can then display my 10 videos without stray channels. not ideal, but will work.